# Xcode framework conflict between amazon and facebook

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, amazon-s3

I'm getting a conflict with duplicate sbjson files in the Facebook sdk and amazon sdk.  I am also using the aviary sdk which required that I set my linker flags to -ObjC -all_load.

The amazon framework is quite big, I only need the s3 uploader classes.

What's the best way to resolve these issues?